# Missing dist/main.js in visual studio 2017 professional

Tags: javascript, node.js, asp.net-mvc, npm, aurelia

I have Aurelia JS Application. I am running these command gulp -g and gulp build in node.js command prompt. I'm not getting dist/main.js directory.

I am facing these two issue :

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Error: (SystemJS) Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:11309/dist/main.js
    Error loading http://localhost:11309/dist/main.js

How can i resolve it?

Comment: what flavor of aurelia app do you have?
was it created with CLI? or from a starter kit?
or was it from some kind of VS template?
Please specify.

Comment: I have vs template where i want to install dependency.

Comment: for vs templates the dist will appear under wwwroot directory
if you are still exploring aurelia, try aurelia-cli. create an app targeting dotnet.core with it.
or google for recent SPA templates beta from microsoft
they have aurelia template with webpack middleware and F5 just works

Comment: Here's more info on that template: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/